# Index management in magento 1.3

Tags: index, magento-1.3

I want to run indexing in magento 1.3 but i dont find indexing option in system tab.
Whats the issue?
how can we run indexing through command in magento 1.3

Answer (score 0):

Please find below step :

step 1 :

```
cd [MAGENTO_ROOT]/shell/
```

step 2 :

```
ls -l

php indexer.php --status
```

step 3 :

```
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price
```

OR

```
php indexer.php --reindexall
```

If you want to reindex in background, your command should look like this

```
nohup php indexer.php --reindexall
```

**I hope its very helpful to you**

Comment: I dont find any shell folder in my magento root

Comment: copy that folder from here - https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror

Comment: Sure?? It wont affect my code right? Only the shell folder i need to copy?

Comment: yes, please try it.

Comment: i am getting this error  https://prnt.sc/oldlqy

Comment: Please confirm Mage.php path. I check with m1.3 file already exist in app/Mage.php

Comment: Its not there. how to add that?

Comment: My suggestion to verify your magento files with fresh magneto1.3

Comment: If i try indexing Rebuild flat catalog product https://prnt.sc/oli0uz it always give this error https://prnt.sc/oli19y, even if i try after long time

Comment: Please chk log.

Comment: i am getting this error https://prnt.sc/oluwyo